# Outlook (new) doesn't show Gmail account content

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail

The new Outlook client in Windows 11 doesn't show anything on a set up Gmail account.

Account is shown but clicking any of its folder shows no message in that folder.

IMAP is enabled online in Gmail but still nothing.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you followed https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/add-a-gmail-account-to-outlook-70191667-9c52-4581-990e-e30318c2c081 and https://support.google.com/a/answer/9003945?hl=en ? In particular, use Oauth2 login.

Comment: I did but that didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

Solution was well hidden but it finally works:

[Fix problems connecting your Google account to the Microsoft Cloud](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/fix-problems-connecting-your-google-account-to-the-microsoft-cloud-6b54d709-f8e9-4f61-8e4d-245d0a52bdd6)

Key issue was step 3, enabling folders.

Pretty convoluted, you have to go to *Settings*, *Labels*, *Show in IMAP*.

As soon as I selected them all, it immediately worked.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to configure your Gmail account to IMAP type in New Outlook?
You'll need to click Create Account, then click on the x in the top right corner, and then select Configure Your Account.

[image]

Comment: Thanks but that part works.

Comment: Yes, this is what you need to do to configure your IMAP account on the Outlook side. But those steps provided in your article need to be completed.